# Unable to copy from assets folder to sdcard

Tags: android, assets, tesseract

I'm trying to copy from my assets folder to my sd card but everytime i tried it always said file not found. Here is my code :

```
  if (!(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "tessdata/eng.traineddata"))
                .exists()) {
            try {

                AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
                InputStream in = assetManager.open("/assets/tessdata/eng.traineddata");
                // GZIPInputStream gin = new GZIPInputStream(in);
                OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + "tessdata/eng.traineddata");

                // Transfer bytes from in to out
                byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                int len;
                // while ((lenf = gin.read(buff)) > 0) {
                while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                    out.write(buf, 0, len);
                }
                in.close();
                // gin.close();
                out.close();

                Log.d("", "Copied eng.traineddata");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d("",
                        "Was unable to copy eng.traineddata "
                                + e.toString());
            }
        }
```

can someone help me?

Comment: What's the path of the file it couldn't write to? Do all directories of that path exist?

Answer (score 1):

In the future, please post the entire stack trace, not just your interpretation of an error message.

At minimum, this is probably not what you want:

```
InputStream in = assetManager.open("/assets/tessdata/eng.traineddata");
```

The `assets/` directory in your project is part of the path that you provide to `open()` on an `AssetManager`. So, unless you have `assets/assets/tessdata/eng.traineeddata` in your project (note the duplicate `assets/`), you probably want:

```
InputStream in = assetManager.open("tessdata/eng.traineddata");
```

Comment: i've tried that and this is the error message : 2719-2719/com.example.rhesa.myapplication D/﹕ Was unable to copy eng.traineddata java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0tessdata/eng.traineddata: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: @RhesaJonathan: As I indicated in my answer, it would help in the future if you **post the entire stack trace**. That being said, either the `0tessdata` directory does not exist (you certainly are not creating it in the code that you show above), or perhaps you are testing on an emulator that lacks external storage.

Comment: `/storage/emulated/0tessdata/eng.traineddata` you forgot an / so try  `/storage/emulated/0/tessdata/eng.traineddata`

Comment: `+ "tessdata/eng.traineddata");` should be  `+ "/tessdata/eng.traineddata");`.